# Slowness in Data::Random

Tags: perl

Hi i'm using **[`Data::Random`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Random)** module to generate **Random Dates** but its very slow for generating sample data of **1 Million**. How to increase the speed of it ? Here is the code i have tried with.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Data::Random qw(:all);

my $randDate_Start = '1900-01-01';
my $randDate_End = '2010-12-31';

open Outfile, ">", "D:/Test.txt";

for(0..1000000)
{
     my $randDate = rand_date( min=>$randDate_Start, max=>$randDate_End);
     print Outfile $randDate."\n";
}

close Outfile;
```

is there any other way to generate **Random Dates**

Comment: Generate fewer sample data?

Comment: @ialarmedalien: the speed of a car is not dependent on the distance you drive and the speed of Data::Random is not influenced by number of generations you do.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger but the time taken for your car journey is dependent on the distance travelled. Then again, it's not the destination, it is the journey that matters.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger is there any other way to generate random date ?

Comment: @lazy - a quick google search reveals http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/Random_Date_Time_Value_Generator.php, http://api.lrs.org/docs/random-date-generator, plus other online options...

Comment: the number "100000000" is 100 milion not 1 milion....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html).

It shows a 6 fold increase in performance as demonstrated by the below benchmarks.

And if you cache the possible date values, you can get a pretty much instantaneous result of all 1 million values:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Benchmark;
use Data::Random qw(:all);
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $randDate_Start = '1900-01-01';
my $randDate_End   = '2010-12-31';

my $tp_start = Time::Piece->strptime( "$randDate_Start 12:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %T" );
my $tp_end   = Time::Piece->strptime( "$randDate_End 12:00:00",   "%Y-%m-%d %T" );
my $tp_days  = ( $tp_end - $tp_start )->days;

my @tp_cached = map { ( $tp_start + ONE_DAY * $_ )->strftime('%Y-%m-%d') } ( 0 .. $tp_days );

# Compare Data Methods
timethese(
    1_000_000,
    {   'Data::Random'         => sub { rand_date( min => $randDate_Start, max => $randDate_End ) },
        'Time::Piece'          => sub { ( $tp_start + ONE_DAY * int rand $tp_days )->strftime('%Y-%m-%d') },
        'Time::Piece (cached)' => sub { $tp_cached[ rand $tp_days ] },
    }
);
```

Outputs:

```
Benchmark: timing 1000000 iterations of Data::Random, Time::Piece, Time::Piece (cached)...
Data::Random: 61 wallclock secs (60.20 usr +  0.07 sys = 60.27 CPU) @ 16592.00/s (n=1000000)
Time::Piece: 10 wallclock secs ( 9.95 usr +  0.01 sys =  9.96 CPU) @ 100401.61/s (n=1000000)
Time::Piece (cached):  0 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.08 CPU) @ 12500000.00/s (n=1000000)
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the second technique what @Glenn recommends, without any optimisation

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Calc qw(Delta_Days Add_Delta_Days);

#create an array for each day
my $numdays = Delta_Days(1900,1,1, 2010,12,31) + 1;
my @dates = map { sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d", Add_Delta_Days(1900,1,1, $_)) } 0..$numdays; 

say $dates[ rand($numdays) ] for(1..100_000_000);
```

running

```
$ time perl dat | wc -l
 100000000

real    0m32.227s
user    0m31.439s
sys     0m1.159s
```

for `100_000_000`. For 1 milion is 1.2 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

I would start by unrolling the loop.  You may not be able to unroll it a million times, but you can probably unroll large number of times and loop a lot less.  That will help to speed it up as it does not have to branch back for the next item.  I did a short test and it was about a 5 to 10 fold speedup.  Here is what I would propose for the loop of 1 million (if I have my math correct :))

```
# Declare the variable before the loop
my $randDate;
# Statement is what we want to execute a number of times
my $statement = "$randDate = rand_date( min=>$randDate_Start, max=>$randDate_End);print Outfile \$randDate.\"\\n\";"
# Replicate the statement 1000 times 
$statement = $statement x 1000;
# Get the time we started (to the second)
my $start = time();
# Loop 1000 times to make a 1 million items
for(0..1000)
{
  # Evaluate the 1000 statements
  eval($statement);
}
# Determine the amount of time it took
my $diff = time() - $start;
# Print out the time
print "Time taken is: $diff\n";
```

When I did this, it took 107 seconds if I looped a million times, and 28 seconds if I used the above method to generate 1 millions items.

If that is not enough speed, then you may have to make a routine to generate your dates.  Given the range, there would be 111 year and at 365.25 days per year, that would be a range of 40543 dates to make. That could be generated once at the start.  You could make a array with each date for the time frame.  Then using rand you can generate a number between 0 and 40543.  That would give you and index into the array for the date to select.  This is a bit more work than the above if above does provide sufficient speedup.

Comment: thanks !!! i would try your approach for *1 Million* now and then i have to try for *1 Billion* too !

can you give sample for **Routine** ? i never heard it before...

Comment: 0..1000 is 1001 times, not 1000 times

Comment: your code is very much faster because the eval is failing.  there's no way unwrapping is going to give that kind of speed increase.

Comment: You are correct.  I found the issue and have update the code example and updated times as well.  Thank for pointing that out. Will have to watch answering questions before I go to sleep.